# Android Java Cannot find local variable

Tags: java, android, mobile

[image][image]**My MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {//My MainActivity

ArrayList<Response> responses = new ArrayList<>();
private String BASE_URL = "https://covid-193.p.rapidapi.com/";
RecyclerView recyclerView;
MyRecycleViewAdapter myRecycleViewAdapter;

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycleViewCovid);
   Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
           .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
           .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());//this is convert json

   Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

   Covid19WebApi covid19WebApi = retrofit.create(Covid19WebApi.class);
   Call<Covid19Model> call = covid19WebApi.getData();//this is call api interfacee method

   call.enqueue(new Callback<Covid19Model>() {
       @Override
       public void onResponse(Call<Covid19Model> call, retrofit2.Response<Covid19Model> response) {
               responses = (ArrayList<Response>) response.body().getResponse();//This is my Api response 232 items
               LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                myRecycleViewAdapter = new MyRecycleViewAdapter(responses);//My Adapter passing data in my Adapter
                recyclerView.setAdapter(myRecycleViewAdapter);
       }
       @Override
       public void onFailure(Call<Covid19Model> call, Throwable t) {
         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,t.getLocalizedMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();//this is toast message failure
       }
   });
```

}

**My Adapter**

```
 public class MyRecycleViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecycleViewAdapter.ViewHolder> 
 {
 private ArrayList<Response> responseArrayList;
public MyRecycleViewAdapter ( ArrayList<Response> responseArrayList) {
    this.responseArrayList = responseArrayList;//Response data items in My Adapter
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyRecycleViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());//Api passing data added this layout 
    View view  = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout,parent,false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyRecycleViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.setData(responseArrayList.get(position));//Api Items List
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return responseArrayList.size();
}


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView continent;
    TextView country;
    TextView population;
    TextView casesNew;
    TextView caseActive;
    TextView caseCritical;
    TextView caseRecovered;
    TextView caseM_pop;
    TextView caseTotal;
    TextView deathsNew;
    TextView deathsM_pop;
    TextView deathsTotal;
    TextView testsM_pop;
    TextView testsTotal;
    TextView day;
    TextView time;
    TextView Deaths;
    TextView Tests;
    TextView Cases;
    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {//My ViewHolder Connect Api data and View Layout TextView
        super(itemView);
        continent = itemView.findViewById(R.id.continentName);//My layout Textview id
        country = itemView.findViewById(R.id.countryName);
        population =itemView.findViewById(R.id.populationName);
        casesNew = itemView.findViewById(R.id.CaseNewName);
        caseActive = itemView.findViewById(R.id.casesActiveName);
        caseCritical=itemView.findViewById(R.id.criticalName);
        caseRecovered=itemView.findViewById(R.id.recoveredName);
        caseM_pop = itemView.findViewById(R.id.M_popName);
        caseTotal = itemView.findViewById(R.id.totalCases);
        deathsNew = itemView.findViewById(R.id.deathsNewName);
        deathsM_pop = itemView.findViewById(R.id.deaths1M_pop);
        deathsTotal = itemView.findViewById(R.id.totalDeaths);
        testsM_pop = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tests1M_pop);
        testsTotal = itemView.findViewById(R.id.testsTotal);
        day = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dayName);
        time = itemView.findViewById(R.id.timeName);
        Cases = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Cases);
        Deaths = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Deaths);
        Tests = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Tests);

    }
    private void setData(Response response){
        Response res = response;
        continent.setText(res.getContinent());//Debugging this TextView Api data is null 
        country.setText(res.getCountry());
        population.setText(res.getPopulation());
        casesNew.setText(res.getCases().getNew());
        caseActive.setText(res.getCases().getActive());
        caseCritical.setText(res.getCases().getCritical());
        caseRecovered.setText(res.getCases().getRecovered());
        caseM_pop.setText(res.getCases().get1MPop());
        caseTotal.setText(res.getCases().getTotal());
        deathsM_pop.setText(res.getDeaths().get1MPop());
        deathsNew.setText(res.getDeaths().getNew());
        deathsTotal.setText(res.getDeaths().getTotal());
        testsM_pop.setText(res.getTests().get1MPop());
        testsTotal.setText(res.getTests().getTotal());
        day.setText(res.getDay());
        time.setText(res.getTime());
        Tests.setText(res.getTests().toString());
        Cases.setText(res.getCases().toString());
        Deaths.setText(res.getDeaths().toString());
    }

}
```

}

[image: My Debug Photo]

**My Problems**

Please Help me What is the Problem?
I pull the data with the Api, but when I debug, I see that the data comes to My MainActivity and is added to the Adapter from there, but when the data reaches the Viewholder, it becomes null when set to the TextView. I don't understand what the problem is.

**My Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#8BC34A"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/continentName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:hint="continent"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/countryName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:hint="country"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/continentName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/populationName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:hint="population"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/countryName" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dayName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:hint="day"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/populationName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timeName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:hint="time"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dayName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/CaseNewName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:hint="new"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/timeName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/casesActiveName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:hint="active"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/CaseNewName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/criticalName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:hint="critical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/casesActiveName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/recoveredName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:hint="recovered"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/criticalName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/M_popName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:hint="1M_pop"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recoveredName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/totalCases"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:hint="total"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/M_popName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/deaths1M_pop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:hint="1M_pop(deaths)"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/totalCases" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/deathsNewName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:hint="new(Deaths)"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/deaths1M_pop" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/totalDeaths"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:hint="total(deaths)"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/deathsNewName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tests1M_pop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:hint="1M_pop"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/totalDeaths" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/testsTotal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:hint="total(tests)"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tests1M_pop" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Deaths"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:hint="Deaths"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/testsTotal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Tests"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:hint="Tests"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Deaths" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Cases"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:hint="Cases"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Tests" />

</LinearLayout>"
```

Comment: There is no View with android:id="@+id/recoveredName" in your layout file?

Comment: Please share the relevant layout aswell

Comment: I added my own layout

Comment: Oh, sorry, the TextView is null in the debugger screenshot because execution stopped on the line where it will be assigned. My bad :(

Comment: No Problem  Bö macht Blau

Comment: What is the problem my code?

Comment: Sorry, urgent xmas business ...  When you write " Api data is null " in `setData()`, do you mean `res.getContinent() == null`?

Comment: The data is displayed up to the TextView population, but the data after it is null.

Comment: OK. When you pass the ArrayList into the Adapter in `onResponse()`, you have 232 items in the list. Can you check for the 200th item whether the required data is not null at his time?

Comment: Since the 200-th item is what you had in your debugger in this question... I'm currently trying to find out where exactly the data "disappears"

Comment: It's disappearing after the population, now I'll take a picture

Comment: the first two data are coming, then null comes

Comment: @Zaur Farrukhzada Can you share demo project so we can debug? Thanks

Comment: The problem may be on the server side... are you sure that the response contains the data you'd like to show in the first place? Technically an ArrayList with 232 items might have lots of elements where most of the fields are null

Comment: First check the api have the response of Continent or not

Comment: If I throw the picture above, please see, the information comes ( Deepak Shukla)

Comment: The data is coming, but it doesn't see the ID of the textview

Comment: Problem is solved

Comment: A parameter to some of the setText() calls is an int. Therefore the setText(int) overload that attempts to set the text with a resource id is used instead of setText(CharSequence) that uses a string.

To explicitly use setText(CharSequence), use e.g. setText(Integer.toString(earth.someintegervalue))